# How to select the optimal lag between an independent and dependent variable in a panel regression?

Tags: r, regression, panel, lag

I am considerably new to statistics and self-learnt R so please bear with me if my question appears silly:

I am doing a multivariate panel regression by country-months. I want to find out how much I should lag my dependent variable by, in relation to my independent variable(s), using a statistical method (as opposed to just using theory).

According to answers I found on other forums, it appears (I don't actually know whether this is appropriate for my purpose and any other suggestions would be very welcome) I should be using the function VARselect(). I am however confused where in the formula I should insert my independent variable and dependent variable, as well where to indicate the country and time variable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this function from the vars package?

Comment: Seems more like a question about statistical modeling. Such questions belong on [stats.se]. I don't see a specific programming question here that's right for this site.

Comment: @Ouistiti Yes it is from the vars package, thanks!